# How to include more data on Series on Highcharts

Tags: c#, .net, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm using Highcharts under C# .NET
I want to include more data to include and show them on Series.

All classes of Series (ColumnSeriesData, PieSeriesData... limit us to a number of a specific fields bellow:

```
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public double? ColorIndex { get; set; }
    public Hashtable CustomFields { get; set; }
    public PieSeriesDataLabels DataLabels { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public PieSeriesDataDragDrop DragDrop { get; set; }
    public string Drilldown { get; set; }
    public PieSeriesDataEvents Events { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public double? Labelrank { get; set; }
    public double? LegendIndex { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? Selected { get; set; }
    public bool? Sliced { get; set; }
    public double? Y { get; set; }
```

How can i add a personalised field ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each class in Highcharts.NET or Highstock.NET contains the `CustomFields` property where you can define fields that will later be thrown in JS. It should be added in pairs: property name and value.

**API example:** https://dotnet.highcharts.com/Help/Highcharts/html/class_highsoft_1_1_web_1_1_mvc_1_1_charts_1_1_spline_series.html#a911f05a5827c3d33cc5dceb79bb55b24

Comment: I found it but i didn't found the way to add my new fields and values to this CustomFields of type Hashtable. I found a function Add but i didn't found the way to use it. Can you give me an Exemple please ?

Comment: It is used in the standard way. Just like the `Hashtable` type is used in C#. An example from Microsoft's website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-7.0